# Beat and Logstash - Connection reset by peer

Tags: logstash, filebeat

I have in the same machine `Elasticsearh`, `Logstash` and `Beat`/`filebeat`.

`Filebeat` is configured to send information to `localhost:5043`.
`Logstash` has a pipe configuration listening on port `5043`.

If I ran `netstat -tuplen` I see:

```
[root@elk bin]# netstat -tuplen | grep 5043
tcp6       0      0 :::5043                 :::*                    LISTEN      994        147016     31435/java
```

Which means logstash loaded the pipe and is listening on the expected port.

If I `telnet` to `localhost` and port `5043`:

```
[root@elk bin]# telnet localhost 5043
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
^CConnection closed by foreign host.
[root@elk bin]#
```

Which means the port is open.

However when I read the `filebeat`'s log, I see:

```
2017-02-15T17:35:32+01:00 INFO Home path: [/usr/share/filebeat] Config path: [/etc/filebeat] Data path: [/var/lib/filebeat] Logs path: [/var/log/filebeat]
2017-02-15T17:35:32+01:00 INFO Setup Beat: filebeat; Version: 5.2.1
2017-02-15T17:35:32+01:00 INFO Loading template enabled. Reading template file: /etc/filebeat/filebeat.template.json
2017-02-15T17:35:32+01:00 INFO Loading template enabled for Elasticsearch 2.x. Reading template file: /etc/filebeat/filebeat.template-es2x.json
2017-02-15T17:35:32+01:00 INFO Elasticsearch url: http://localhost:5043
2017-02-15T17:35:32+01:00 INFO Activated elasticsearch as output plugin.
2017-02-15T17:35:32+01:00 INFO Publisher name: elk.corp.ncr
2017-02-15T17:35:32+01:00 INFO Flush Interval set to: 1s
2017-02-15T17:35:32+01:00 INFO Max Bulk Size set to: 50
2017-02-15T17:35:32+01:00 INFO filebeat start running.
2017-02-15T17:35:32+01:00 INFO No registry file found under: /var/lib/filebeat/registry. Creating a new registry file.
2017-02-15T17:35:32+01:00 INFO Loading registrar data from /var/lib/filebeat/registry
2017-02-15T17:35:32+01:00 INFO States Loaded from registrar: 0
2017-02-15T17:35:32+01:00 INFO Loading Prospectors: 1
2017-02-15T17:35:32+01:00 INFO Starting Registrar
2017-02-15T17:35:32+01:00 INFO Start sending events to output
2017-02-15T17:35:32+01:00 INFO Prospector with previous states loaded: 0
2017-02-15T17:35:32+01:00 INFO Loading Prospectors completed. Number of prospectors: 1
2017-02-15T17:35:32+01:00 INFO All prospectors are initialised and running with 0 states to persist
2017-02-15T17:35:32+01:00 INFO Starting spooler: spool_size: 2048; idle_timeout: 5s
2017-02-15T17:35:32+01:00 INFO Starting prospector of type: log
2017-02-15T17:35:32+01:00 INFO Harvester started for file: /tmp/logstash-tutorial.log
2017-02-15T17:35:32+01:00 INFO Harvester started for file: /tmp/yum.log
2017-02-15T17:35:38+01:00 ERR Connecting error publishing events (retrying): Get http://localhost:5043: read tcp [::1]:40240->[::1]:5043: read: connection reset by peer
```

And the message `2017-02-15T17:35:41+01:00 ERR Connecting error publishing events (retrying): Get http://localhost:5043: read tcp 127.0.0.1:39214->127.0.0.1:5043: read: connection reset by peer` is repeated ad-nauseam.

I am missing a elephant in the room? Why is the connection "reset by peer"?

---

*pipeline.conf*

```
input {
    beats {
        port => "5043"
    }
}
# The filter part of this file is commented out to indicate that it is
# optional.
# filter {
#
# }
output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

*filebeat.yml*

```
###################### Filebeat Configuration Example #########################

# This file is an example configuration file highlighting only the most common
# options. The filebeat.full.yml file from the same directory contains all the
# supported options with more comments. You can use it as a reference.
#
# You can find the full configuration reference here:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/index.html

#=========================== Filebeat prospectors =============================

filebeat.prospectors:

# Each - is a prospector. Most options can be set at the prospector level, so
# you can use different prospectors for various configurations.
# Below are the prospector specific configurations.

- input_type: log

  # Paths that should be crawled and fetched. Glob based paths.
  paths:
    - /tmp/*.log
    #- c:\programdata\elasticsearch\logs\*

  # Exclude lines. A list of regular expressions to match. It drops the lines that are
  # matching any regular expression from the list.
  #exclude_lines: ["^DBG"]

  # Include lines. A list of regular expressions to match. It exports the lines that are
  # matching any regular expression from the list.
  #include_lines: ["^ERR", "^WARN"]

  # Exclude files. A list of regular expressions to match. Filebeat drops the files that
  # are matching any regular expression from the list. By default, no files are dropped.
  #exclude_files: [".gz$"]

  # Optional additional fields. These field can be freely picked
  # to add additional information to the crawled log files for filtering
  #fields:
  #  level: debug
  #  review: 1

  ### Multiline options

  # Mutiline can be used for log messages spanning multiple lines. This is common
  # for Java Stack Traces or C-Line Continuation

  # The regexp Pattern that has to be matched. The example pattern matches all lines starting with [
  #multiline.pattern: ^\[

  # Defines if the pattern set under pattern should be negated or not. Default is false.
  #multiline.negate: false

  # Match can be set to "after" or "before". It is used to define if lines should be append to a pattern
  # that was (not) matched before or after or as long as a pattern is not matched based on negate.
  # Note: After is the equivalent to previous and before is the equivalent to to next in Logstash
  #multiline.match: after


#================================ General =====================================

# The name of the shipper that publishes the network data. It can be used to group
# all the transactions sent by a single shipper in the web interface.
#name:

# The tags of the shipper are included in their own field with each
# transaction published.
#tags: ["service-X", "web-tier"]

# Optional fields that you can specify to add additional information to the
# output.
#fields:
#  env: staging

#================================ Outputs =====================================

# Configure what outputs to use when sending the data collected by the beat.
# Multiple outputs may be used.

#-------------------------- Elasticsearch output ------------------------------
output.elasticsearch:
  # Array of hosts to connect to.
  #hosts: ["localhost:9200"]

  # Optional protocol and basic auth credentials.
  #protocol: "https"
  #username: "elastic"
  #password: "changeme"

#----------------------------- Logstash output --------------------------------
#output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
  hosts: ["localhost:5043"]

  # Optional SSL. By default is off.
  # List of root certificates for HTTPS server verifications
  #ssl.certificate_authorities: ["/etc/pki/root/ca.pem"]

  # Certificate for SSL client authentication
  #ssl.certificate: "/etc/pki/client/cert.pem"

  # Client Certificate Key
  #ssl.key: "/etc/pki/client/cert.key"

#================================ Logging =====================================

# Sets log level. The default log level is info.
# Available log levels are: critical, error, warning, info, debug
#logging.level: debug

# At debug level, you can selectively enable logging only for some components.
# To enable all selectors use ["*"]. Examples of other selectors are "beat",
# "publish", "service".
#logging.selectors: ["*"]
```

Comment: are you using the beats input?

Comment: Can you show the relevant portions (with redactions if need be) of your Logstash (/etc/logstash/conf.d/filename.conf) and Filebeat (/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml) configurations?

Comment: Yes, I am using beats input.
@Signus My Logstash pipeline is the one that can be found on [Elastic website](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/advanced-pipeline.html). I will paste both as an edit of this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found out:

```
#-------------------------- Elasticsearch output ------------------------------
output.elasticsearch:
...
...

#----------------------------- Logstash output --------------------------------
#output.logstash:
...
...
```

Where I should have:

```
#-------------------------- Elasticsearch output ------------------------------
#output.elasticsearch:
...
...

#----------------------------- Logstash output --------------------------------
output.logstash:
...
...
```

Answer (score 2):

> Get http://localhost:5043

This suggests that your filebeat configuration and what Logstash is configured to listen for are not in sync. [Logstash has a `beats {}` input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-beats.html) specifically designed to be a server for beats connections. The default port is 5044. On the beats side, [the Logstash Output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/logstash-output.html) needs to be used to connect to that server. Doing it this way ensures both sides are speaking the same language, which that error suggests is not the case.

Comment: I set port 5043 on both elements, Beats and Logstash's input.

Answer (score 0):

In your Filebeat configuration try changing tls to ssl. See the list of breaking changes

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was missing logstash template options

`output.logstash:
  hosts: ["localhost:5044"]
  template.enabled: true
  template.path: "/etc/filebeat/filebeat.template.json"
  index: "filebeat"`